# How do I roll back master to a prior commit, make a change, and then reapply everything that was rolled back?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a master branch and a development branch both are in sync with each other currently.

I need to roll back my master branch to a prior commit (at least 30 commits back) so I can make a change and commit it. Then I would like to reapply everything and bring it back up to the current date in sync with development.

Can I do this by reverting master to a prior commit? Make the change, commit it, and then merge development into master. Would that work? Is there an easier or more appropriate way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What you want is called a `rebase`.

Comment: You should have your question in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this: `rebase`/`cherry-pick`/`reset`+`merge`. It'll look something like this:

```
Before:

* C4 <- [master] [development]
* C3
* C2
* C1

reset master to C1, then commit Alteration A1:

* A1 <- [master]
| * C4 <- [development]
| * C3
| * C2
|/
* C1

Option 1: Bring up to date /w development (via merge):

* C5 <- [master]
|\
| * C4 <- [development]
| * C3
| * C2
* | A1
|/
* C1

Option 2: Bring up to date /w development (via rebase or cherry-pick):

* C4' <- [master] [development2]
* C3'
* C2'
* A1
| * C4 <- [development]
| * C3
| * C2
|/
* C1
```

But you should have a really good reason for rolling `master` back and changing history -- it'll probably be better to just add more changes on top instead.

Perhaps you could provide some more details so a better/specific recommendation can be given?

Comment: I have a huge release with multiple commits that was in development. I then merged  development (multiple times) in with master because I thought the release was ready. However, its not ready yet and I have a hot fix I need to make in production.

Comment: The best thing to do for the `master` branch would be to revert each `merge of development` and then proceed as normal by committing the hotfix on top. Note that reverting a merge involves picking one of the two parents of the merge commit (usually the first parent). This way, the git history reflects reality exactly as it happened: `dev` was merged, reverted, and a change was added.

Comment: @ProfessorGT has this been useful? Can I get a question upvote if it has?

Answer (score 1):

You can use git reset --hard master@{1.days.ago}

Also you can specify the time like  1.hours.ago, 5.days.ago and etc

After that you can apply git commit.

Comment: Yea, but then can I reapply all the reset history by merging in development? or will that not work?

Comment: It'll reset all you changes and then you can apply anything .